# Find Function to Find If Cell Contains a Partial Match if Applicable

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a function that takes two input arguments, `boardtype` and `subsysnum` and then finds the row index that has that specific combination. However, if subsysnum column is blank then continue on. Only some cases will have a `subsysnum` value. `boardtype` will have to be an exact match. For the purpose of the function, I have written so far, `boardtype` and `subsysnum` are defined both as strings above. `column` defined when calling the function will be either `3` or `5`

I have so far called the worksheet that has the lookup table in it and believe I have found the row index for the `boardtype` now I just need to incorporate if `subsysnum` value can be found in the second column then find the row combination index, else continue with the blank second column to find the lookup value. This is what my data looks like

[image]

Using the table above say for example my boardtype = AX-6 and my subsysnum = WD1234TEST I want the macro to get the row index of 9 since subsysnum = WD1234 is contained in the subsysnum number WD1234TEST. If subsysnum = WD298588 trial, then the row index return should be 8 since it is contained in the value. Finally, if subsysnum value cannot be found in column 2, then it should return a row index of 7 for AX-6 with the blank cell next to it.

This is what I have tried so far, however, I am not getting any value for `GetClock`

```
Function GetClock(boardtype As String, subsysnum As String, column As Long, Optional partialFirst As Boolean = False) As Variant  
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, board_range As Range, firstAddress As String
    FunctionName = "GetClock"
    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\LookupTable.xlsx")
    Set ws = wbSrc.Worksheets("Clock")

    Set r1 = ws.Columns(1)
    Set r2 = ws.Columns(2)

With r1
        Set board_range = r1.Find(What:=boardtype, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True) ' find board type row
            If Not board_range Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = board_range.Address ' save board type address
            Else
                    ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & IIf(ErrorMsg = "", "", "") & SectionName & ": " & "Board " & boardtype & " could not be found in lookup table" & vbNewLine
                Exit Function
            End If
        Do While Not board_range Is Nothing 
            Set subsysnum_range = r2.Find(What:=subsysnum, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=IIf(partialFirst, xlPart, xlWhole), MatchCase:=True)
                    GetClock = ws.cells(board_range.row, column).value
            Exit Function 

        Set board_range = r1.Find(boardtype, board_range)
            If board_range.Address = firstAddress Then
                GetClock = ws.cells(Range(firstAddress).row, column).value 
                If GetClock = 0 Then
                    ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & IIf(ErrorMsg = "", "", "") & SectionName & ": " & "lookup table missing value" & vbNewLine
                End If
                Exit Function
            End If
     Loop
End With
End Function
```

[image]

UPDATE: Where `Column(13)` represents the column in the `Data Sheet` that has the `subsysnum` stored

```
Function GetClock(boardtype As String, subsysnum As String, column As Long, Optional partialFirst As Boolean = False) As Double  
Dim wbSrc As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, board_range As Range, firstAddress As String, subsysnum_range As Range, rng_board As Range, rng_subsys As Range
FunctionName = "GetExternalClock"
Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\LookupTable.xlsx")
Set ws = wbSrc.Worksheets("Clock")

Dim wb As Workbook, dataws As Worksheet
Set wb = Workbooks("S93.xlsm")
Set dataws = wb.Worksheets("Data Sheet")
Set r1 = ws.Columns(1)
Set r2 = ws.Columns(2)

With r1
    Set board_range = r1.Find(What:=boardtype, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True) ' find board type row
        If Not board_range Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = board_range.Address ' save board type address
        Else
                ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & IIf(ErrorMsg = "", "", "") & SectionName & ": " & "Board " & boardtype & " could not be found in lookup table" & vbNewLine
            Exit Function
        End If
Dim subsys As Range, cell As String
    Do While Not board_range Is Nothing ' while board type is not nothing look for value of cell in column 2
        For Each subsys In Range("B3:B12")
            cell = subsys.value
            Set subsys_rng = dataws.Columns(13).Find(What:=cell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=IIf(partialFirst, xlPart, xlWhole), MatchCase:=True)
            If cell = "" Then
            GoTo Skip
            Else
                GetClock= ws.cells(subsys_rng.row, column).value
            End If
 
 Skip:
    Next subsys
    Exit Function

     'if intersect.value does not equal sysnum, then it will set board_range below only after it has checked every matching cell in column 1
    Set board_range = r1.Find(boardtype, board_range)
        If board_range.Address = firstAddress Then
            GetClock= ws.cells(Range(firstAddress).row, column).value ' boardtype row index with empty cell in r2
            If GetClock= 0 Then
                ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & IIf(ErrorMsg = "", "", "") & SectionName & ": " & "lookup table missing value" & vbNewLine
            End If
            Exit Function
        End If
    Loop
End With
Exit Function
End Function
```

| Board | Subsystem | Min | Max | Min | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AX |  | 10 | 40 | 10 | 400 |
| AX-11 |  | 10 | 400 | 10 | 400 |
| AX-12 |  | 100 | 750 | 100 | 750 |
| AX-13 |  | 10 | 550 | 10 | 550 |
| AX-4 |  | 10 | 400 | 10 | 400 |
| AX-6 |  | 125 | 550 | 125 | 550 |
| AX-6 | WD298588 | 40 | 500 | 40 | 500 |
| AX-6 | WD1234 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| AX-7 |  | 125 | 750 | 125 | 750 |
| AX-8 |  | 125 | 550 | 125 | 550 |

Comment: Why does your function contain so many parameters, since you are asking about a perfect match  in the first column and a match in the second one? Then, what a match should mean? Should it be to the left part of the string or anywhere inside the string? And finally, what to be the function return? You are mentioning the row of the best match. If so, why returning a `Variant` type and not a `Long`?

Comment: @FaneDuru I change it to return a `Double` I am looking for the function to find the row index that has an exact match in first column and a partial match in second column.

Comment: Then, it should be a `Long` (to accept maximum number of rows in a worksheet)... You did not say anything about the other two parameters, which are not contained in the question description (in words, I mean) and position of the second string in the column one (left or anywhere)?

Comment: @FaneDuru `column` for this case will either be `3` or `5` and the second string `subsysnum` refers to the second column to the left of the first column

Comment: And what signification should `column` have? I mean in terms of processing.

Comment: @FaneDuru it just allows me to be able to use the function for different columns, so I do not have to hard code in column 3 for examples, I could pull numbers from column 3 to 6 if I wanted

Comment: What pulling numbers from columns does mean? To return that numbers instead of the row number?

Comment: @FaneDuru yes, using the row index that would be found for the `boardtype` and `subsysnum` I then need to save the value within the cell that is in say for example row 9, column 3 to be `GetClock` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, check the next function:

```
Function GetClock(wbSrc As Workbook, boardtype As String, subsysnum As String, Optional column As Long = 0) As Long
   Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, i As Long, dict As Object
   
    Set ws =  wbSrc.Worksheets("Clock")  'set the sheet where the data to be processed exists
    lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in A:A
    
    arr = ws.Range("A2:F" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster iteration/processing
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the necessary dictionary
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'iterate between the array rows
        'if first array column is = boardtype and subsysnum exists in the second column (B:B):
        If arr(i, 1) = boardtype And InStr(arr(i, 2), subsysnum) > 0 Then
             If column = 0 Then 'if no column parameter
                dict(1) = i + 1 'it returns the matching row (+ 1 because the array starts from the second row ("A2:F" & lastR)
             Else
                dict(1) = arr(i, column) 'it returns the value in the 'column' column
             End If
        ElseIf arr(i, 1) = boardtype Then 'if not the above two matches, but only a match between first column and `boardtype':
           If column = 0 Then
                dict(2) = i + 1 'it returns the matching row
             Else
                dict(2) = arr(i, column) 'it returns the value in the 'column' column
             End If
        End If
    Next i
    If dict.Exists(1) Then 'if both matches have been done:
        GetClock = dict(1)  'it returns the dict(1) value
    ElseIf dict.Exists(2) Then 'if only a match of the first column:
       GetClock = dict(2)   'it returns the dict(2) value
    End If
End Function
```

It can be tested being called as:

```
Sub testGetClock()
   Dim wbSrc As Workbook
   On Error Resume Next
     Set wbSrc = Workbooks("LookupTable.xlsx") 'try setting the open workbook
    On Error GoTo 0
    'if it is not open (being Nothing), set it by opening:
    If wbSrc Is Nothing Then Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\LookupTable.xlsx")
    
   Debug.Print GetClock(wbSrc, "AX-6", "WD298588")
   Debug.Print GetClock(wbSrc, "AX-6", "WD1234")
   Debug.Print GetClock(wbSrc, "AX-6", "WD1234", 3)
End Sub
```

If you use the `column` parameter and the returned value **may be a string** the function return have to be changed from `Long` to `Variant`...

Now, in case of no match it returns zero (`0`).

Please, send some feedback after testing it

Comment: I struggled to understand fully how to use `dict` I have updated my code above to reflect what I am viewing

Comment: @resu_student But no need to adapt anything. Just use the code as it is. I used Late binding and no need of any reference. Didn't you test the above function? If tested, didn't it return what you need? What do you want adapting? I need to close my laptop in less then 10 minutes. If no answer in this time period, I will replay tomorrow. Basically, a dictionary has unique keys (1 and 2 in our case) and a value, which can be any object, string, long, array etc.

Comment: @resu_student A wrong answer is one not returning what you asked for.

Comment: I tried out your code and it is not returning the correct value. When I test it should be returning 100 but it is returning 110

Comment: @resu_student What is 110? I cannot see it in the rable you show. If tested on other data, **is the header  on the first row**?

Comment: I meant 1. I had changed the values in row 9 to be 110, 220, 330, 440 to see if the macro was struggling to read the values since I had it set to be a double

Comment: @resu_studen Why did you changed, before seeing the code working as you need? How could I understand what you mean to also understand what's happening? How did you call the function? Did you use the testing sub i posted above and you are referring to the third testing line? If  not, how did you call the function?

Comment: Yes I used the code above. I changed the data from 1 to 110 because when I was debugging and seeing that it was returning 100, I wanted to make sure the code was not adding on two 00 to the back of the 1.

Comment: @resu_studen Do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk in stalled? I would like to see the wander connecting to your computer, if possible. But before that, can you show **how you exactly call the function** to return a bad value? Theoretically, it is not possible...

Comment: I call it like this `exclockmin_min = GetClock(boardtype, subsysnum, 3, partialFirst:=True)`

Comment: @resu_studen I am afraid you did not call it properly... The above function **does not have a fourth parameter** and I cannot understand how it works without immediately raising an error about that. Then, if you adapted somehow to accept that parameter, i cannot know what else you did. An finally you did not say anything about  "TeamViewer or AnyDesk" issue. Without seeing what's happening in your workbook I am out of ideas. The code **worked as it should in my computer, on my workbook.,,**. I do not even have the testing data, anymore. I helped other people in the meantime. May I connect?

Comment: What fourth parameter are you referring to? My function only requires the 3. No I do not have TeamViewer or AnyDesk installed.

Comment: @resu_studen `boardtype, subsysnum, 3, partialFirst:=True` counts 4 parameters. And giving them in this way i cannot understand anything... Did you try `Debug.Print GetClock("AX-6", "WD1234", 3)`? What does it return?

Comment: Yes, it returns 125 instead of 1. The values coming from the picture in the initial post. So it is not finding the partial match

Comment: This is not possible.  Please, copy the call exactly as you use it in your code.

Comment: `Debug.Print GetClock("AX-6", "WD1234", 3)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249706/discussion-between-faneduru-and-resu-student).

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop over an array would be easier to manage, along with caching the lookup table between calls:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print GetClock("AX-6", "missing", 3)            '125
    Debug.Print GetClock("AX-6", "WD1234", 3)             '1
    Debug.Print GetClock("AX-6", "WD298588", 3)           '40
    Debug.Print GetClock("AX-6", "WD1234Test", 3)         '125
    Debug.Print GetClock("AX-6", "WD1234Test", 3, True)   '1
End Sub


Function GetClock(boardtype As String, subsysnum As String, column As Long, _
                  Optional partialSubSys As Boolean = False) As Variant
    
    Static data As Variant
    Dim r As Long, rNoSub As Long, rMatchSub As Long, rMatch As Long, wldCard As String
    
    If IsEmpty(data) Then 'data not already cached?
        With Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\LookupTable.xlsx")
            data = .Worksheets("Clock").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
            .Close False
        End With
    End If
    
    wldCard = IIf(partialSubSys, "*", "") 'using a wildcard?
    For r = 2 To UBound(data, 1)
        If data(r, 1) = boardtype Then
            If Len(data(r, 2)) = 0 And rNoSub = 0 Then
                rNoSub = r       'first matched line with no subsystem listed
            ElseIf subsysnum Like data(r, 2) & wldCard Then  '<<FIXED
                rMatchSub = r    'subsystem matched
                Exit For         'stop checking
            End If
       End If
    Next r
    
    rMatch = IIf(rMatchSub > 0, rMatchSub, rNoSub) 'prefer two-part match...
    If rMatch > 0 Then 'any match (one- or two-part) ?
        GetClock = data(rMatch, column)
    Else
        GetClock = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        'populate error message as needed
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: What is the purpose of checking for `Empty(data)` and I am looking for partial match not a wild card?

Comment: There's no need to open the file on every call to the function: if you read the lookup table into a Static variable it can persist between calls.  `IsEmpty(data)` checks to see if the lookup table has already been read into `data`.  The function uses the wildcard "*" with `Like` to check for a partial match if specified when the function was called.

Comment: I have updated my code to view how I have used `partialFirst` however it is loading the wrong number

Comment: Had my wildcard check the wrong way round - see "FIXED" above.

Comment: I tested your FIXED code, however, it is returning the value of 125 when it should be returning the value of 1.

Comment: With what inputs?  It would really help if you could provide a copy-paste version of your data table screenshotted above.  No-one really wants to type that out.

Comment: I called it like `x = GetClock(boardtype, subsysnum, 3)` I added my table, the formating got a bit messed up and split the table in two.

Comment: You can use https://thisdavej.com/copy-table-in-excel-and-paste-as-a-markdown-table/ to create a useable table.

Comment: Thank you I have typed out the table

Comment: But now you've opened a new question...

Comment: I would delete this question but I am not allowed to

Comment: If you were to delete this question that others have spent quite some time on trying to help you, they would be rightly quite annoyed at that.  Edited above with a Test sub - works as expected given your sample data table.

Comment: Precisely that is why I am not deleting it in case others can use the answers if they have a problem like this.

Comment: For `wildcard` should there be a `"*"` before `partialSubSys` incase there could be text before the `subsysnum`?

Comment: If you need "contains" and not "starts with" then you can update that line to `ElseIf subsysnum Like wldCard  & data(r, 2) & wldCard Then`

Comment: Since your code uses `partial` why does `wildcard` need to be used? I did test your code and it does currently return the value that I am testing for at the moment. I am just trying to understand the code as it is much more complex than what I am used to working with.

Comment: Start by reading up on `Like` and how `*` is used with that as a wildcard. If you don't using any wildcards then `Like` behaves like `=`.  All my code does is add a "*" when  `partialSubSys` is True

Comment: For this case then the 'pattern' is `wldCard & data(r, 2) & wldCard`